# Save password salt in database in aspnet identity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am using aspnet identity for create,update delete,login and logout new users in my asp.net WebAPI application. When i create new user its automatically storing the PasswordHash and security stamp in the database. But now my want to store Password salt string in database . I have searched a lot but unable to do it. Is it possible to save salt by using aspnet identity? If yes then how?

[image: My current AspNetUser table]
[My current AspNetUser table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssrun.png)

Comment: Just concatenate the salt and the hash, and store them in the PasswordHash column.

Comment: Any particular reason that you need to implement a second round of salting? Apart from the default salt implementation?

Answer (score 0):

**Code first**

**1. Create Application User class**

You need to create a class that inherits from IdentityUser.

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string UserSalt {get;set;}    
    }
```

**2. Context**

Then you need to adjust your models (let's suppose you're using EF code first).

Your application context (you can create a special class for ApplicationRole too):

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string> {...}
```

^ Just in case your application is an identity provider and your application context represents your identity context.

**3. Adjust model**

Add property to model builder:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("IdentityProvider.Models.ApplicationUser", b =>
{
...
  b.Property<string>("UserSalt");
... 
}
```

**4. Adjust relationships**

Also make sure that everywhere you had IdentityUser as entity name in your code first approach to switch it to ApplicationUser.